# Is there a way to prevent line breaks in man pages?

Tags: linux, man, roff

Title says it all. I'm just trying to avoid awkward line breaks between words. I read somewhere that in {,t,g}roff using `~` in place of a space should do it, but that doesn't seem to work for man pages (I get a literal `~` instead).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it in `man man-pages`: `word1\ word2`.